# How to flip the normals of the collider mesh in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, mesh, normals

I have a sphere in Unity and have used a script to flip the normals so I can see a 360 texture on the inside. I'm doing this because eventually I want to play a video on the inside, and also have other spheres inside hat can be thrown around and bounce off the inside walls of the outer sphere. The problem is, despite the normals of the sphere facing inwards, the collision is still standard. Objects within the sphere just fall straight through.

Do I need to add to my script to include the collision mesh?

Comment: I think you need to use a mesh collider and invert the normals of the mesh. The sphere collider detect collisions coming from inside. The downside is the mesh is more computationally expensive than a sphere collider.

Comment: But I should be able to flip the normals using code like I did with the main Mesh.

Comment: You will likely need to mark the mesh as `convex` in addition to flipping the normals, and may need to split it into 2 hemispheres. You _might_ look at doing your own collision detection. The maths should be pretty simple for this case: assuming sphere is centered at the origin, if the distance to the center of the thrown ball >= (sphere radius - ball radius), you've collided.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have non-convex MeshColliders behave as Rigidbodies in Unity, you need to fake the walls as a series of convex colliders, approximate with box colliders maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you recalculated the mesh with inverted normals for the rendering, now just get the mesh collider of the game object using `GetComponent`, and then set its shared mesh as the mesh u calculated above.

```
MeshCollider abcd = this.GetComponent<MeshCollider>();

abcd.sharedMesh = mesh;
```

here "newmesh" is the mesh I calculated with flipped normals for the rendering

edit - you need to get the `MeshCollider` from the `GetComponent`, idk why stackoverflow is removing it when I'm trying to write it in <>